# Move include under the relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: Android layout]

I am trying to move the `include` below the Relative Layout (with a toolbar inside it). Now as you can see from the picture they overlap.

Here is my sample code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
  </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: give marginTop as you have width of toolbar

Comment: if i give `marginTop` to the toolbar then the toolbar is re-positioned but i want them to not overlap

Comment: no no don't give margin to toolbar but the layout you are including do the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your toolbar inside a AppBarLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```